# mod_rewrite: find file based on a regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I would like to use mod_rewrite to redirect to a page if I can find a file based on a pattern determined from the URI

The path to the file to match

```
/path/to/dir/cat1_cat2_cat3
```

The HTTP request

```
http://example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3
```

The mod_rewrite configuration:
-1st line: extract cat1, cat2, and cat3 with regular expressions
-2nd line: attempt to match file using regular expression variables
-3rd line: if match successful redirect to page

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$
RewriteCond /path/to/dir/$1_$2_$3 -f
RewriteRule /some_page.html
```

For some reason it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond /path/to/dir/$1_$2_$3 -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /some_page.html
```

The `RewriteCond` line is evaluated *after* `mod_rewrite` sees that the `RewriteRule` matches, so you can use the `$N` values there.

Your original version would have worked too, except that: you were matching against `QUERY_STRING` which is the part after the `?` in a request -- you probably meant `REQUEST_URI`; you should have used `%N` to reference back to the previous `RewriteCond`; and you were missing the pattern part of the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: +1 I had no idea you could use the RewriteRule backreferences in the RewriteCond. I learn something on Stack Overflow every day, it seems like.

Comment: @Compeek No, it's not very intuitive -- you tend to think the `RewriteCond`s are checked first since they are written first. But for efficiency it makes sense to check the `RewriteRule` pattern first, since `RewriteCond` checks can be much more expensive (file checks, DB lookups, ...).